# Exchange 2007: Different Sending EHLO/HELO FQDN based off sending domain

Tags: exchange-2007

Single Exchange 2007 Server environment. DNS records in place.

I want to change the FQDN exchange gives when it's *sending* mail from different domains.

For example if a user has two domains he's sending out as, (user@bob.com and user@joe.com), configured through exchange, i want the ehlo to read "mailserver.bob.com" when he sends out as "user@bob.com" but when he sends out as "user@joe.com" i want the FQDN given by exchange to read "mailserver.joe.com".

I was thinking of doing this through different send connectors, but the Send Connectors and their respective FQDNs are chosen by the receipt's address, not the sending address.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "sender-based routing". There's no built-in functionality in E2K7 to do what you want, but the pieces are there to put it together with custom code. It could be done by having someone code up a custom Routing Agent for you. If you're brave and want to give it a go, have a look here for some good starter material:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897564.aspx
- http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/12/04/431755.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579185.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called choose from that will change the from fields per user.  You can get it from the publisher [here](http://www.ivasoft.com/choosefrom2007.shtml).  The behaviour you are experiencing is by design in exchange and cannot be changed without some sort of event sink.